# vim-go - how to configure goimports group like GoLand

Tags: go, vim, editor, vim-go

How can I set up goimports on vim to group all the imports like in the GoLand?

[image]

I already have this configuration for autosave on .vimrc:

```bash
let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"
```

Comment: I use [gofumpt](https://github.com/mvdan/gofumpt). Rule import on gofumpt is `std imports must be in a separate group at the top`

Comment: I've recently switched to `gopls`, but used `goimports` before that. It grouped imports as expected (std packages at the top, in alphabetical order, other packages in a separate group). To distinguish between my own module imports and third party ones, I just added a blank line between the two. Not sure what you're trying to do _exactly_ though

Comment: That plugin you are using has a dedicated issue tracker.